# Add `Where column1 in ('a', 'b', 'c')` filter in EntityDataSource

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, npgsql

I'm using .NET 4.6.1 with EntityFramework 6.1 + Npgsql + Postgresql, I have a model:

```
public class PosItem
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public virtual Guid? TargetBusinessUnitId { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets which BusinessUnit this PosItem will be used on.
    /// </summary>
    [ForeignKey("TargetBusinessUnitId")]
    public virtual BusinessUnit TargetBusinessUnit { get; set; }
}
```

And a GridView to show `PosItem` in a ASP.NET webpage, Now I want to add a condition check for avoid list all `PosItem` to the GridView, then I'm trying to add the filter condition in `EntityDataSource.Where` property, this is the string I've applied to it(for simplify, just hard coded here):

```
GridDataSource.Where = "\"it\".\"TargetBusinessUnitId\" in ('b66f959e-1668-4abc-bebf-13ac3a2136b9','d0fe3b8d-78d9-49ad-b71a-c9e147825eb8')"
```

also, I've tried:

```
GridDataSource.Where = "it.TargetBusinessUnitId in ('b66f959e-1668-4abc-bebf-13ac3a2136b9','d0fe3b8d-78d9-49ad-b71a-c9e147825eb8')"
```

Both give me an exception like:

> System.Data.Entity.Core.EntitySqlException: 'The query syntax is not
>   valid. Near term ',', line 6, column 68.'

I've tested the sql statement in PgAdmin:

> select * from "PosItems" as "it" where "it"."TargetBusinessUnitId" in
>   ('b66f959e-1668-4abc-bebf-13ac3a2136b9','d0fe3b8d-78d9-49ad-b71a-c9e147825eb8')

it works good.
So any idea?